# Not continuous Not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

The function : $f(x)= 1$ if  $x$ is rational and $f(x)= -1 $ if $x$ is irrational  is not continuous so its not differentiable

The definition of dervative is :

Let $I$ subset $R$ be an interval and $f$:$I$ _ $R$ and let c belongs to $I$ we say that a real number $l$ is the derivative of $f$ at  c  if $\forall$  $\epsilon >0 $
there exist  $\delta >0$ such that if x belongs to $I$ satiefies $ 0<|x-c|<\delta $ , then

| $\frac{(f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ - $l$ | < $\epsilon $

$f'(c)$= $l$

But how is it not differentiable using the definition ?

Comment: What is the definition of a derivative? Does it look like it exists for your function? That's how it's not differentiable.

Comment: the limit that represent the derivative at a point is not defined, hence $f$ doesnt have derivative at any point.

Comment: How it is not define at any point?

Comment: @Tasneem According to *your attempt to calculate the limit that you have read in the definition of differentiable function*, could you please explain us "how" it would exist?

Comment: Standard result you need to know: If $f'(a)$ exists, then $f$ is continuous at $a.$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking why it is not differentiable, why not just try and calculate the derivative?

For example, what is the derivative at $0$? Well by definition, it is

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

and this limit does not exist. Similarly, you can replace $0$ with any other real number, and the resulting limit will still not exist.

Comment: Then it will be 0/0 for all x ???

Comment: @Tasneem No, the limit is not $0/0$. There is no such thing as $0/0$. The limit **does not exist**. I strongly advise you go back and re-read a little about limits. You are clearly missing basic knowledge you **really** need before you can learn about derivatives.

Comment: The definition of derevative is : for all epsilon >0 there exist delta >0 such that if 0<|x-c|<delta then |(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)|< epsilon!

Comment: Oh I understand thank you very much

Comment: @Tasneem That's not the definition of a derivative

Comment: No it is ,f is differentiable at c if lim (f(x)-f(c))/(x-c) exist

Comment: We study this this definition of derevative from "introduction to real analysis batrle" section 6.1 : let I subset R be an interval let f:I_R and let c belongs to I we say that a real number k is the derivative of f at c if  given any epsilon >0 there exist delta >0 such that if  0<|x-c|<delta  then |(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c) -k |< epsilon

Comment: @Tasneem Yup, that's the definition. But that's not what you wrote before :)

Answer (score 0):

If a function is differentiable, it must be continuous. Just use the definition of a derivative to show this is always true. However, you can have continuous functions which are differentiable *nowhere* (not like $f(x)=|x|$ which is differentiable everywhere except $0$).

Comment: if the function is differentiable then its continuous so the contrapositive is also true ,how that for the function above?

Comment: the function you gave is not continuous, and since it isn't continuous, it cannot be differentiable. If a function isn't continuous, then it is *never* differentiable. This is just the contrapositive of saying a differentiable function is *always* continuous.

Comment: And how its not differentiable?

Comment: look at $lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, note that for *any* $x$ you plug in, the limit is not defined. Since the limit is not defined, it is not differentiable.

Comment: also if you know differentiable implies continuous, and if you know what contrapositive means, then you already know not continuous means not differentiable.

Comment: We study this this definition of derevative  : f is differentiable at c if for all epsilon >0 there exist delta >0 such that if 0<|x-c|<delta  l is real number then |(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c) -l |< epsilon

Comment: I don't know if I can help you until you learn what a derivative is, several comments have explained why the function is not differentiable. If it's not continuous, it's not differentiable, end of proof. The definition you gave is not the definition of derivative, it is the definition of continuity. Also learn to typeset, it's very tedious and cumbersome to read what you write unless you use the MathJax formatting. We all had to learn it at some point, you should learn it too if you wish to productively use this site.